# javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Object named: entityConverter not found

Tags: jsf, converters

Well, I have a custom faces converter like bellow:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "entityConverter", forClass = AbstractBean.class)
public class EntityConverter implements Converter {
```

And in some part of my XHTML, i use this like that:

```
<p:selectOneMenu converter="entityConverter"
                rendered="#{clienteMB.bean.pessoaFisica != null}"
                value="#{clienteMB.bean.pessoaFisica.estadoCivil.descricao}"
                effect="fade">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione um Sexo" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{clienteMB.estadosCivis}" var="estadoCivil"
                    itemLabel="#{estadoCivil.descricao}" itemValue="#{estadoCivil}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

But when i try to enter in this page, i got the following error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Object named: entityConverter not found.
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createConverter(ApplicationImpl.java:1338)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValueHolderRule$LiteralConverterMetadata.applyMetadata(ValueHolderRule.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:159)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    ...
```

I have no idea why this is happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This,

```
@FacesConverter(value = "entityConverter", forClass = AbstractBean.class)
```

is not valid. You should choose to use the one or the other. This was ever reported as [issue 1650](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1650) and shortly fixed, but quickly reverted with the following comment:

> The following text was added to the Javadocs of FacesConverter in JSF 2.2:
>
> The preceding text contains an important subtlety which application users should understand. It is not possible to use a single @FacesConverter annotation to register a single Converter implementation both in the by-class and the by-converter-id data structures. One way to achieve this result is to put the actual converter logic in an abstract base class, without a @FacesConverter annotation, and derive two sub-classes, each with a @FacesConverter annotation. One sub-class has a value attribute but no forClass attribute, and the other sub-class has the converse.
>
> In this light I will close this issue as Invalid.

Your concrete problem is effectively caused because the `forClass` is actually being used, but `value` not. Thus, `converter="entityConverter"` didn't find any converter.

Comment: this is very strange, because i have exactly the same Class in another project and everything works fine.

Comment: The effects may depend on the JSF impl/version used.

Comment: i'm using jsf-api and jsf-impl 2.16 in both projects, the pom.xml is exactly the same.

Comment: Well, i don't know what is the problem but i copied all pom.xml from my another project to this project and everything works fine. Thanks anyway @BalusC

Comment: There is something really bad. I have the similar problem - even when I use only this annotation, the converter is not found. @FacesConverter("cisDateConverter"). It works only if it is declared in faces-config.xml
There are reported another classloading issues - we have one ear with many wars inside and only some of them use JSF. But JSF reports classloading issues even from those without JSF (AS Payara).

Comment: @BalusC All dependencies are in ear/lib, wars have no own dependencies. JSF, eclipselink etc. are provided by the application server.

Comment: But you pointed in good direction, the converter class is in one and only submodule ... thank you! :-)

Comment: No duplication needed, then it would have no sense to use application servers. The problem is only with JSF/Mojarra, with nothing else.
The classes are reported as warnings on deployment, but now everything works. My problem was that JSF did not see the convertor class placed in war's only dependency (even placed in it's own WEB-INF/lib as you wrote and I forgotten that in my comment).
So now remain only those deployment warnings :)